# Using %v in Apache LogFormat definition matches ServerName instead of specific vhost requested

Tags: apache-2.2

We have an application which uses a DNS wildcard, i.e. *.app.example.com. We're using Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu Hardy. The relevant parts of the Apache config are as follows.

In /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vlog
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/app.example.com:

```
ServerName app.example.com
ServerAlias *.app.example.com
...
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/vlogger -s access.log /var/log/apache2/vlogger" vlog
```

Clients access this application using their own URL, e.g. company1.app.example.com, company2.app.example.com, etc.

Previously, the `%v` in the `LogFormat` directive would match the hostname of the client request, and we'd get several subdirectories under /var/log/apache2/vlogger corresponding to the various client URLs in use.

Now, `%v` appears to be matching the `ServerName` value, so we only get one log under /var/log/apache2/vlogger/app.example.com. This breaks our logfile analysis because the log file has no indication of which client the log relates to.

I can fix this easily by changing the `LogFormat` to this:

```
LogFormat "%{Host}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vlog
```

This will use the HTTP Host: header to tell vlogger which subdirectory to create the logs in and everything will be fine.

The only concern I have is that this has worked in the past and I can't find any indication that this has changed recently.

Is anyone else using a similar config, i.e. wildcard + vlogger and using `%v`? Is it working fine?

Comment: Graeme,
it's the same over here.
2 installs of apache 2.0.54 and 2.2, both configured with LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
2.0 shows the host header name (virtual host), 2.2 the host name. So it's not that you weren't right. BTW: Thanks for your "%{Host}i" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%v is and always has been the canonical name of the vserver, ive just checked the manuals for both 1.3, 2.0 and 2.2 and they all say

```
%...v:          The canonical ServerName of the server serving the request.
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_log_config.html

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html

Comment: Yeah, I saw those.... somehow both I and my colleague had convinced ourselves/each other that we'd always used %v. Looking at all the evidence against us it seems we are wrong. We've changed it to use %{Host}i now, which is *probably* what it was previously anyway. :-/

Answer (score 6):

There is also [%V](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html) (note the cap) and the [useCanonicalName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) option

Comment: Thanks, but you're OT :)
We were discussing how to log the (virtual host) name of the requested web site.

Comment: ...which is exactly what %V does. Logs the hostname of the virtual server which handled the request. The useCanonicalName option lets you control wether you want the server's opinion of it's name, or the client's opinion of the name. %{Host}i is always the client's opinion, so %V is another way to do that, plus a way to do what %{host}i cannot do.

Comment: This is the answer you were looking for, it's not OT.  You were probably using the upcase %V and forgot.